# Can I submit published articles to arXiv as well?

Tags: publications, copyright, arxiv, online-publication

I have several math research articles on my site.

Some of my articles are published in open access journals.

Some of my articles are currently available only from my site.

I may probably publish something in a closed access journal.

The question: Should I put these kinds of articles at arXiv (and possibly replace articles on my site with redirect to arXiv)? I think yes, because it would increase visibility of my articles, as many people search on arXiv and/or receive arXiv mailing lists.

Is it ethical to put an already published article also at arXiv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can put your published articles on arxiv just for visibility purposes, but you will be having problems with the copyright of the journals and conferences in which your work is published. Essentially, the editors will not get too busy to track you down, but it is not ethical.

There is one way to go around this problem, publish in arxiv the draft versions of your articles, the ones that are a little bit different from the published ones. In that case you would not have any kind of ethical issues (you can also put them on your webpage, but always look to the copyright forms)

Good luck!

Comment: It is not always (nor in all legislations) true that you'll automatically be violating copyright or doing something unethical!

Comment: It is also not true that posting a draft vesion to the arxiv is compatible with the copyright policies of the journal. That being said, most journals I know of in mathematics allow you to put an "Author version" on the arXiv, that is, as long as you don't use the version that is typeset by the journal, it is usually fine. But you will have to check the individual journal's policies.

Comment: In the field of CS, I know uncountable cases of Professors that put draft versions on arxiv. If they can put the author version, well good for them.

Comment: Usually math journals allow arxiving, but if they don't its the journal who is behaving unethically.  Allegedly the reason the ask for copyright transfer is to help and protect the author not to attack the author.

Answer (score 25):

I suggest you first of all check

- the copyright transfers you signed
- the publisher's FAQ on rights you retain as author
  Many publishers nowadays allow you to self-archive the version of the manuscript that passed the review. Some do not allow self-archiving on public repositories (but e.g. Elsevier makes an exception explicitly for arXiv). For a quick overview have a look at the [SHERPA/RoMEO site](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/).
- and your local copyright legislation.
  E.g. the [German UrhG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/__38.html) now allows secondary publication (e.g. to arXiv) of your manuscript (including the version with exactly the content of the published paper) for journal contributions that were financed mainly by public grants.

Comment: These agreements also sometimes distinguish between the final author copy which you can usually post as a preprint and the final journal copy (after copyediting and typesetting) which you often can't post.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit not a mathematician, I like to add this: if your work was supported by a public agency and got accepted for a peer-reviewed journal, public agencies may have a policy to make these manuscripts available for everybody.

See (as example) the [public access policy](http://publicaccess.nih.gov/) by the U.S. National Institute of Health:

> The NIH Public Access Policy ensures that the public has access to the published results of NIH funded research. It requires scientists to submit final peer-reviewed journal manuscripts that arise from NIH funds to the digital archive PubMed Central immediately upon acceptance for publication.  To help advance science and improve human health, the Policy requires that these papers are accessible to the public on PubMed Central no later than 12 months after publication.

Depending on the journals listed in [PMC](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/), some articles are "Free Access" immediately (if published in journals like like *European Journal of Histochemistry*), delay of six months (like *Organogenesis*) or twelve (like *Optics Express*), for example.

While not a mathematician, I'm glad to see NIH *does* fund work in mathematics, too (according to their publication database).  Of course, NIH's public access policy is in regard to the single articles published, not the entire journals listed.