# Can I post on Arxiv a final paper published on PLOS ONE?

Tags: arxiv, open-access, preprint, plos-one

Can I post on Arxiv a final paper published on PLOS ONE? I would like to put on Arxiv the final edited paper, replacing the old pre-print. Can I do that?
I am wondering if this violates any rule of either PLOS or Arxiv, or is OK.

On the PLOS website it says:

> All content published by PLOS is Open Access and distributed under a Creative Commons Attribution (CC BY) license. You should credit the appropriate PLOS journal in your coverage and provide a link to the freely available article in any online coverage.

I also saw other answers to this question, but nothing specific for PLOS: [Can I submit published articles to arXiv as well?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17625/can-i-submit-published-articles-to-arxiv-as-well)

Which license should I choose?

Comment: If it is published at PLOS under CC BY, then literally anyone can upload it anywhere they want, as long as the authors are properly credited and the license is mentioned. Since arxiv even allows you to select the same license I see no problem there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Read the [CCBY license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/): you are allowed to share (copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format) and adapt (remix, transform, and build upon the material
for any purpose, even commercially) the material as long as you attribute (you must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made). So you can put the paper on arXiv, as long as you attribute.

Comment: Thanks! Attributing on Arxiv means that I post the paper as the author right? Also the authors are in the pdf itself, so I think that would an attribution, right?

Comment: @Forinstance I'm not a lawyer, but I imagine yes.

Comment: @Forinstance: Make sure to list the other authors in the arxiv metadata as well, not only in the PDF itself.

Comment: Just got a confirmation via email by PLOS (they took some time :) ), here is the answer that confirms yours: PLOS ONE publishes all of the content in the articles under an open access license called “CC-BY.” [...] Additional permissions are not required. You can read about our open access license here: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/licenses-and-copyright
Therefore, I can confirm you can submit the final version of your manuscript to a preprint server.